# Is it possible to create a hybrid Dvd/Bluray?

Tags: bluray, dvd

I'm am doing a short Product demo for our company, intended as a give-away on Dvd (for the moment only burned Discs, no pressed ones).

The whole filming and editing is done in 1080p and since the video is less than 10 minutes long, I wondered whether it's possible to author a hybrid type of disc? I am aware that there exists a thing called "hybrid bluray/dvd" from Pony/Canon which basically consists of two entirely separated disc-structures on different layers ([see here](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/hybrid_blu-ray_dvd_disc_announ.php)) however, that is not what I am looking for.

I try to find out if a disc-structure can be created where the DVD "VIDEO_TS"-folder is on the same UDF-filesystem as the "AVCHD"-Bluray folder. When the Disc is inserted in a DVD-Player, it just ignores the Bluray-content. The tricky bit probably is to get a Bluray-player to read the HD-content rather than to fall back into DVD-compatibility mode, I guess.

Does anybody know of such a technology and possibly how this can be achieved?

Thanks!

Comment: Would it work to put the HD video into DVD VOBs, and have a menu to choose SD vs. HD? (dvd players would crash if you selected the HD menu entry, since they'd then try to read a VOB containing HD h.264, or HD mpeg2).  Apparently PC players at least can play HD video in a DVD structure.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to create a hybrid DVD/Blu-Ray disk in the manner which you describe.  The reason for this is that in addition to the digital formats between the two being different the physical media is different too.  You would require a multi-layer or multi-sided disk such as the one you linked to and different digital data on each side.

DVD players read DVDs using a certain frequency of light and a set spacing between the track grooves (it really is laid out kind of like the grooves on an old phonograph record but microscopic).  BluRay players and disks use a different frequency of light and closer spaced grooves.  Initially this meant it was necessary to have separate laser systems for DVD and BlueRay in any combined player.  More recently optical systems were developed that could work for either format and made combined drives much cheaper to produce on mass.

I'd suggest the cheapest way would be to get a writable BlueRay and try gluing a writeable DVD to the back of it.  You would need quite thin disks to do this though as they would not fit inside standard drives.  Buying a combined DVD and BluRay disk (and writer?) is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can author a Bluray structure and write it to a DVD, and *most* bluray players will "mistake" it for a Bluray and play it nicely.

A DVD player though, will not be able to make any sense of it.